# How do you say plugged a running stream of water into a tube?

Tags: idiomatic-language

How do you say plugged a running stream of water into a tube?

> He **plugged a running stream of water into a tube** and the tube fed
> the water tank.

Is there a way to say this idiomatically? It doesn't sound idiomatic at all.

Comment: Are you talking about a hosepipe? Sorry, I can't quite picture what you mean! Does the tube attach to a tap?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to describe.  Can you perhaps rephrase?  We can't "plug" water into anything.  That doesn't make sense.

Comment: "silo" looks wrong.  A silo is store of grain, or "silage".  Filling it with water would be the "wrong thing".

Comment: What is the source of your example? It doesn't make sense as is. Did you mean stopping water from flowing through a hose/pipe?

Comment: I see other people have closed this for lack of details or clarity. I had read this question as using "plugged into" in the same sense as you would plug electricity into something: meaning "put into", but carrying the extra sense of something that is being continuously provided. I understand feeling unsure if that was really meant, but I also think this interpretation is supported by the text of the question as is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean that the whole stream entered the tube, you could say that he **piped** the stream into the water tank. "Pipe" would be a more common name for the tube than "tube" in this context.